# Como escrever uma página JSP usando caracteres de outras línguas?

Tags: java, jsp, caracteres

Estou escrevendo uma página JSP que usa caracteres japoneses e estou usando o método get,mas quando mudo para o método post ele não funciona. Já tentei usar
charset = Shift_JIS, mas nada!!

Página JSP:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset = UTF-8">
        <title>本</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="SubmitNameServlet"  method="get">
            <label for "name">名前</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Name"/>
       </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Classe do servlet:

```
package servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SubmitNameServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = req.getParameter("nome");
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html><head><title>日本語</title></head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>始めまして " + name + " </h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e poste o que já tem feito.

Comment: Melhorou e muito a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("<html><head><title>日本語</title></head>"));
```

ou crie um metodo:

```
private boolean postEncodedStr(PrintWriter out, String strMsg) {
    try {
        out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(strMsg));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

e use em seu código como:

```
public class SubmitNameServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = req.getParameter("nome");
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

        postEncodedStr(out,"<!DOCTYPE html>");
        postEncodedStr(out,"<html><head><title>日本語</title></head>");
        postEncodedStr(out,"<body>");
        postEncodedStr(out,"<h1>始めまして " + name + " </h1>");
        postEncodedStr(out,"</body>");
        postEncodedStr(out,"</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado por responder , mas poderia  mostrar na sua resposta como fazer uso de ambos os  método  que você indicou ? De modo que fique pronta para ser rodada no servidor!

Answer (score 1):

No seu método `doPost` você seta o encoding pra `UTF-8`. [ServletResponse::setCharacterEncoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#setCharacterEncoding(java.lang.String))

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

A tag `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset = UTF-8">` não é usada quando a página é servida por HTTP, ela só serve pra dizer o encoding quando você salva a página como um arquivo `.html` ou quando você acessa por esse arquivo pela rede como `file://`